# Existence of inverses of limits of bounded operators on Banach space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, inverse

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, let $B(X,Y)$ be the Banach space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, and let $B(Y,X)$ be the Banach space of bounded linear operators from $Y$ to $X$.

Suppose $T,T_0,T_1,\dots\in B(X,Y)$ with $T_n\rightarrow T$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (under the operator norm on $B(X,Y)$).

Suppose further that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $T_n$ is invertible.

Finally, suppose that the sequence $T_0^{-1},T_1^{-1},\dots$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B(Y,X)$ (under the operator norm).

Thus, since $B(Y,X)$ is complete, there is some $S\in B(Y,X)$ such that $T_n^{-1}\rightarrow S$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Must it then be the case that $T$ is invertible with $T^{-1}=S$?

Answer (score 1):

$T_nT_n^{-1}=T_n^{-1}T_n=I$ so $TS=ST=I$. So $T$ is bijective and Open Mapping Theorem shows that $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}=S$.